# Eclipse: autocomplete variables

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to autocomplete a previously declared variable in Eclipse?

E.g. see this code:

```
Intent bookmarksActivity = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this, BookmarksActivity.class);
startActivity(boo
```

I don't get any code completion hints after `boo` however I'm sure something this basic must be possible.

Comment: Did you try ctrl+space?

Comment: That's it. I was expecting the tooltip you get in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, type the CTRL+ SPACE keys together and then use the keyboard arrows to select the desired variable then tap the ENTER key. Nice and easy.
You can also use the CTRL+ SPACE key combo to cycle to "Template Proposals" as well.